# How to access class function from within another function in the same class with Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, class

I am trying to execute a function in my class, triggered by another function.

Here is an example. `Foo` is a class, that when constructed, calls the function `Bar()`. After an animation is complete, I want to `doSomething`, but this does not work, and throws an error.

The code is below or you can test the JSFiddle here.

```js
class Foo
{
    Bar(){
        $("#element").animate({ width : "100%" }, {
            duration : 1000,
            complete : function(){
             console.log("test");
                this.doSomething();
            }
        });
    }

    doSomething()
    {
        // Do something
    }
    
    constructor(){
     this.Bar();
    }
}

var example = new Foo();
```

```css
#cont {
  width: 100%;
}
#element {
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cont"><div id="element"></div></div>
```

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.doSomething is not a function

How can I call the `doSomething()` function in the class from within this function?

Comment: pass an arrow function instead: `complete: () => { ... ` to maintain the lexical reference to `this`.

Comment: @MarkMeyer thank you, this has worked. If you answer I will accept when I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are losing 'this' context. You can use arrow function "complete : ()=>{" or assign that = this and run that.doSomething() for older versions of JS.

Answer (score 1):

By the time you call `this`, it is within the scope of the callback function `complete`. At that point, `this` is referencing the callback function, not the class. Or, knowing jQuery, `this` might be pointing at the `#element` element. You'll need to restructure. The laziest way to do it would be to create a new variable within the class method, assign `this` to it and use that in the function. I am also using `let` here instead of `var` because we want this variable to be block scoped ([whatever that means](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let))

```
class Foo
{
    Bar(){
        let self = this;
        $("#element").animate({ width : "100%" }, {
            duration : 1000,
            complete : function(){
                console.log("test");
                self.doSomething();
            }
        });
    }

    doSomething()
    {
        // Do something
    }

    constructor(){
        this.Bar();
    }
}

var example = new Foo();
```

You can also use arrow functions and the `using` keyword or a `bind` thingy but I'm not that good a programmer and the above concept has worked fine for me so far.